# Eclipse 2018-09 with jdk11 claims that package org.junit is missing even though it is included by maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

my maven project includes junit and builds including running the tests on the command line with maven. However eclipse claims that the package can not be found, I don't understand why eclipse would ignore the dependency.

I am depending on version 4.12 of junit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on the project, then use `Maven`>`Update Project...` to get the build path settings in sync with the `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the version of junit in the pom.xml.
The 3.x version is programmed and 4.x is the annotation method.

Comment: its version 4.12